# PyQt5 self reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I used Qt Designer to design a GUI and use the command in PyQt5 to convert the .ui file to .py. From that, I want to output a messagebox when a button is clicked. I have successfully done it using this line of code on the function of the button listener:

`QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(MainWindow, "Result", "Invalid number entered!")`

I have searched around the internet but I don't understand why this one don't work.

`QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", "Invalid number entered!")`

Does the self their refer to the MainWindow also?

Here is the full source code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        #MainWindow.resize(310, 185)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(310, 185)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("#MainWindow\n"
    "{\n"
    "    background-color:qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, 
    radius:1.696, fx:0.5, fy:0.505682, stop:0 rgba(0, 85, 255, 255), stop:1 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 255))\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "#firstNo_lineedit, #secondNo_lineedit\n"
    "{\n"
    "    \n"
    "    background-color: rgb(28, 255, 123);\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.firstNo_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstNo_lineedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 113, 20))
        self.firstNo_lineedit.setObjectName("firstNo_lineedit")
        self.secondNo_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.secondNo_lineedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 113, 20))
        self.secondNo_lineedit.setObjectName("secondNo_lineedit")
        self.calculate_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.calculate_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 75, 23))
        self.calculate_button.setObjectName("calculate_button")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 81, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 61, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 310, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        # ================= Listeners ===================
        self.calculate_button.clicked.connect(self.basicArithmetic)
        # ============================================

    # ================= Events ===================
    def basicArithmetic(self):
        try:
            firstNo=float(self.firstNo_lineedit.text())
            secondNo=float(self.secondNo_lineedit.text())

            resSum=firstNo+secondNo
            resDiff=firstNo-secondNo
            resMul=firstNo*secondNo
            resDiv=round(firstNo/secondNo,2)

            print("Sum: {}".format(resSum))
            print("Difference: {}".format(resDiff))
            print("Product: {}".format(resMul))
            print("Quotient: {}".format(resDiv))

            toDisplay="Sum: {}".format(resSum)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Difference: {}".format(resDiff)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Product: {}".format(resMul)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Quotient: {}".format(resDiv)

            #QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(MainWindow, "Result", toDisplay)

        except ValueError:
            #QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(MainWindow, "Result", "Invalid number entered!")
    # ============================================

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.calculate_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculate"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First No.:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second No.:"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is the first parameter of the methods (the name is by convention, is not mandatory) of a class that refers to the instance of the same.

For another `QMessageBox.about()` requires as first parameter an object of some kind that inherits from `QWidget` or also None.

If we review the class generated by Qt Designer, we clearly see that it is not a widget, in fact the only objective of that class is to be an interface to fill in another widget:

```
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() # create widget
ui = Ui_MainWindow() # create interface
ui.setupUi(MainWindow) # fill widget
```

Therefore the `self`, the instance of `Ui_MainWindow`, you want to pass is not appropriate because it does not refer to the widget, but the `MainWindow` is a widget, so it works correctly with that change.
Also within the generated file you have the following message:

```
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
```

That message is because if you want to change the design you will have to overwrite the logic that you wrote, such as your `basicArithmetic` method, which makes the project untenable.

PyQt I recommend to create another class that uses the class that generates QtDesigner, I assume that the generated file is called design.py

**design.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        #MainWindow.resize(310, 185)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(310, 185)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("#MainWindow\n"
    "{\n"
    "    background-color:qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5," 
    "radius:1.696, fx:0.5, fy:0.505682, stop:0 rgba(0, 85, 255, 255), stop:1" 
    "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255))\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "#firstNo_lineedit, #secondNo_lineedit\n"
    "{\n"
    "    \n"
    "    background-color: rgb(28, 255, 123);\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.firstNo_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstNo_lineedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 113, 20))
        self.firstNo_lineedit.setObjectName("firstNo_lineedit")
        self.secondNo_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.secondNo_lineedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 113, 20))
        self.secondNo_lineedit.setObjectName("secondNo_lineedit")
        self.calculate_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.calculate_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 75, 23))
        self.calculate_button.setObjectName("calculate_button")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 81, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 61, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 310, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.calculate_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculate"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First No.:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second No.:"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This new class can have the following form:

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from design import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)  

        # ================= Listeners ===================
        self.calculate_button.clicked.connect(self.basicArithmetic)
        # ============================================

    # ================= Events ===================
    def basicArithmetic(self):
        try:
            firstNo=float(self.firstNo_lineedit.text())
            secondNo=float(self.secondNo_lineedit.text())

            resSum=firstNo+secondNo
            resDiff=firstNo-secondNo
            resMul=firstNo*secondNo
            resDiv=round(firstNo/secondNo,2)

            print("Sum: {}".format(resSum))
            print("Difference: {}".format(resDiff))
            print("Product: {}".format(resMul))
            print("Quotient: {}".format(resDiv))

            toDisplay="Sum: {}".format(resSum)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Difference: {}".format(resDiff)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Product: {}".format(resMul)
            toDisplay+="\n"
            toDisplay+="Quotient: {}".format(resDiv)

            #QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)

        except ValueError:
            #QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", "Invalid number entered!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And that is the reason why, in many cases, `self` is seen as the first parameter.

You can find more information at the following link:

- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Comment: Thanks! I still have to build my foundation in OOP. One last questions, what does it means when there is a parameter involved in a class in Python. For example, like this:

`class MainWindow(QMainWindow):`

Comment: @LinkedRom That's called inheritance, just like you inherit your parents' characteristics, the MainWindow class inherits from QMainWindow, so it has all its methods and attributes, that allows you to create a custom window, just like you are a customized version of your parents. :D . 
that is one of the best attributes of OOP, it saves us from writing thousands and thousands of code lines.

Answer (score 0):

No self refers to  `Ui_MainWindow`class where `MainWindow` reffers to  `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`
So when you say  `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Result", toDisplay)` it will treat `Ui_MainWindow` as a parent `QWidget` which is not correct.

when you call `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(MainWindow, "Result", toDisplay)` this time your code will run fine because `MainWindow` is a valid `QWidget` i.e  `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`

hope this helps.